# NestJS and Fastify Post Request File Upload is Unsupported Media Type: Multipart/form-data

Tags: angular, express, post, nestjs, fastify

I am a beginner in Angular and NestJs. I am working on an application that sends a zip file via Post request of the application's runtime log from the front end to the endpoint `/api/v1/logs` . I tested it before using express and Multer to have a server listening on port 5050 and then save it to a local folder and it worked. My goal is to use NestJS to create an API that takes the post request and is able to send the error app log file to an S3 bucket.

I am very new to this but trying my best to figure out and learn so any help or insight at all would be super helpful!

**Problem:**

I am using a query as a DTO and the structure is controller, query, and handler. It uses Fastify, NestJS, and Swagger. I tried looking at fastify-multipart and then I spend a lot of time trying to get the NestJS file Upload technique to work. I am on NestJS 8.0.0 and I am trying to get the post request and then handle the file. However, I always get the error `Unsupported Media Type: Multipart/form-data` . I spend a lot of time on it and I tried making a sample post and query, and it seems to be able to handle the query body fine. However, whenever there is a payload of a file then it results in an error.

```
//log-handler.controller.ts

@Controller('log-handler')
export class LogHandlerController{
    constructor(private queryBus: QueryBus){}
    
    @Post('/api/v1/logs')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async sendAppLog(
        @Body query: PostLogQuery,
        @UploadedFile()
        file:Express.Multer.File
    ){
        console.log(query);
        console.log(file);
        return this.queryBus.execute(query);
    }
}
```

**System Version and Package Versions:**

- NestJs 8.0.0
- Fastify 3.29.2
- Fastify-swagger: 4.8.3
- OpenFin Process Manager Version: RVM = 8.1.0.4
- Node.js: v16.15.0
- Windows 10
- Angular Application with C# .NET backend

**Attempts:**

I tried sending over a binary file and it just resulted in undefined.

- I looked at similar stackoverflow posts and tried their answers and formatting and it still causes the error. In case you are wondering what API is sending the post request.

  - Post Request: https://developer.openfin.co/docs/javascript/stable/tutorial-Application.sendApplicationLog.html
  - Sample Documentation from another Source: https://github.com/built-on-openfin/container-starter/tree/main/how-to/use-logging-apis
- I opened up the apis through the swagger tool at localhost:5050/api . It seemed that the api at /api/v1/logs did not even give the option to take in a file; however, it did give the option of taking in something of the formatted DTO.
- I tested to see if it can take the DTO object and query and it seems to be able to handle that perfectly.

Any Help would be amazing. I am new but really want to learn more.